Issue with query performance coming from mysql to mariadb
we were in the process to migrate from Mysql to MariaDB, but we've encountered a performance issue with several of our queries.
The same (already simplified) query
SELECT
    count(*)
FROM
    vorgang,
    genehmigung,
    kontostand,
    konto
WHERE
    vorgang.mandant_vorgang_s_id IN (-999, 99, 268768, 265382, 257, 102134, 102144, 106530, 133309, 146055, 146494, 253567, 275073, 279352, 292605)
    and genehmigung.vorgang_genehmigung_s_id = vorgang.nr
    and vorgang.mandant_vorgang_s_id = konto.partner_konto_s_id
    and konto.konto_type = 'vorfinanzierungskonto'
    and kontostand.konto_kontostand_s_id = konto.nr; 

(using the exact same database dump in a freshly installed mariadb/mysql and equally sized VM) is finished in ~12s in our tested mysql versions (5.7.27-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 and 9.0.1 MySQL Community Server), but in maria db (10.6.16-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 and 11.4.2-MariaDB-ubu2404) it is still running after 2h.
And the explain of the query clearly tells us where the problem is:
MariaDB (both versions):

explain select count(*) FROM vorgang,genehmigung,kontostand,konto WHERE mandant_vorgang_s_id IN (-999,99,268768,265382,257,102134,102144,106530,133309,146055,146494,253567,275073,279352,292605) and vorgang_genehmigung_s_id=vorgang.nr and mandant_vorgang_s_id=partner_konto_s_id and konto_type='vorfinanzierungskonto' and konto_kontostand_s_id=konto.nr ;
+------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table       | type          | possible_keys                                                                            | key                              | key_len | ref                                      | rows   | Extra                           |
+------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | kontostand  | index         | konto,konto_kontostand_s23                                                               | konto                            | 5       | NULL                                     | 752910 | Using where; Using index        |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | konto       | eq_ref|filter | PRIMARY,konto_partner_konto_s_id,partner_konto                                           | PRIMARY|konto_partner_konto_s_id | 4|4     | kontostand.konto_kontostand_s_id         | 1 (0%) | Using where; Using rowid filter |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | vorgang     | ref           | PRIMARY,vorgang_mandant_vorgang_s_id,mandant_vorgang                                     | vorgang_mandant_vorgang_s_id     | 4       | konto.partner_konto_s_id                 | 4950   |                                 |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | genehmigung | ref           | genehmigung_vorgang_genehmigung_s_id_status,vorgang_genehmigung_s105,vorgang_genehmigung | vorgang_genehmigung_s105         | 4       | vorgang.nr                               | 1      | Using index                     |
+------+-------------+-------------+---------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------+--------+---------------------------------+


MySQL (both versions):

explain  select count(*) FROM vorgang,genehmigung,kontostand,konto WHERE mandant_vorgang_s_id IN (-999,99,268768,265382,257,102134,102144,106530,133309,146055,146494,253567,275073,279352,292605) and vorgang_genehmigung_s_id=vorgang.nr and mandant_vorgang_s_id=partner_konto_s_id and konto_type='vorfinanzierungskonto' and konto_kontostand_s_id=konto.nr ;
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                            | key                      | key_len | ref                                            | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | genehmigung | NULL       | index  | genehmigung_vorgang_genehmigung_s_id_status,vorgang_genehmigung_s105,vorgang_genehmigung | vorgang_genehmigung_s105 | 4       | NULL                                           | 138527 |   100.00 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | vorgang     | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,vorgang_mandant_vorgang_s_id,mandant_vorgang                                     | PRIMARY                  | 4       | genehmigung.vorgang_genehmigung_s_id           |      1 |    13.16 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | konto       | NULL       | ref    | PRIMARY,konto_partner_konto_s_id,partner_konto                                           | konto_partner_konto_s_id | 4       | vorgang.mandant_vorgang_s_id                   |      1 |    10.00 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | kontostand  | NULL       | ref    | konto,konto_kontostand_s23                                                               | konto                    | 5       | konto.nr                                       |   3331 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------------------------------------------------+--------+----------+-------------+

The actual result is roughly 4.5 million counts.
The execution plan of MariaDB makes no sense, why would you start with the largest table and crossjoin that into smaller ones?
Is there anything we can do to optimize the query for MariaDB? Can we somehow generally change the optimization strategy of MariaDB to use the same as Mysql?
Thank you for any insight!
I've added the DDL to a pastebin: https://pastebin.com/nPsKkVxN
I've also noticed if we omit the  vorgang.mandant_vorgang_s_id IN (-999, 99, 268768, 265382, 257, 102134, 102144, 106530, 133309, 146055, 146494, 253567, 275073, 279352, 292605) MariaDB uses the same execution plan as Mysql.

Please use proper join syntax . Add table description (run show create table tableName) for all related tables.

Please use the JOIN...ON syntax.  Please qualify each column with the table name (or alias).  (I am having trouble parsing the query.)

Thank you for your efforts, I've added the DDL of the table as well as fully qualified table names. Since I cannot convert the syntax of the actual query in the legacy system it would be pointless to convert it here.
